# Python 3 Fernet encrypting same message different ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm currently learning python and am trying to make a encryption program that encrypts the same message the same every time, I achieved the encryption process with Fernet.

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided = 'examplepassword'
kpassword = password_provided.encode()

salt = b'H&\xb6\n\xe6@\xdf\x13\x88\x98 Z\xf0\xea,\xca\x05\xd7\x99\x105\xa8\xa2{\xa9F\xe0\x91\x89c)\xf8%@]"u<\xe03|\xe2\re]\'\xb7\x89O2\xf9\x0bY\xf5\xb6<\x80z\\bM\x8dDx'
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm = hashes.SHA256,
    length = 32,
    salt = salt,
    iterations = 100000,
    backend = default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(kpassword))


k = Fernet(key)
example = k.encrypt(b'ABC')
print(example)
```

this code works and encrypts it once as I expect, but Fernet encrypts it different ways every time and I don't know why. if there is any way to make the current program encrypt a message the same way every time please help, or if there is just another way to complete the thing I am trying to do.

Just in case you suggest, no i'm 90% sure that the salt is not the problem as i have tried longer and shorter salts using `os.urandom()`, I have also tried changing the password.

EDIT: i am trying to encrypt an input that a person gives, then someone else gives the same input and i want to compare the encryption's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here. [Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) encrypt uses AES-128 with [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) mode of operation with PKCS7 padding.

The CBC mode requires an IV, and this IV is generated by os.urandom(). So, each run you will have a different IV, and this will change the encryption, see [probabilistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption).

Note: The salt you used is used in Key generation (PBKDF2HMAC), not for the IV of the CBC mode.

Comment: are you able to give me an example on how to "fix" this code so it gives the same encryption for the same set of characters every time?

Comment: Not possible with Fernet. Use [Hazmat](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/). Not ECB is not secure, you should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

Fernet encodes the time a message was generated as meta information, as well as a probabilistically seeded initialisation vector (IV). Hence separate calls will produce different codes:

> A fernet token is the base64url encoding of the concatenation of the following fields:
>
> `Version ‖ Timestamp ‖ IV ‖ Ciphertext ‖ HMAC`
>
> ...
>
> When generating new fernet tokens, the IV must be chosen uniquely for every token. With a high-quality source of entropy, random selection will do this with high probability.

- https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/
- https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md